# Where did RenderPartial() go in ASP.Net 5 MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 there is the `Html.RenderPartialAsync` but no `Html.RenderPartial`. Doing some digging I see that there is a new thing called `View Components` which seem to be a more powerfull version of partial views but are geared toward dynamic things. Did MVC 6 drop `RenderPartial` or am I just not finding any documentation on it? I want to use it to just include a static navigation menu file into the main layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RenderPartial` really does not exist  in `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"`. However, it has been implemented already and probably will be included in `6.0.0-rc2`. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3705.

The workaround is to use `RenderPartialAsync`, it works fine.